# no encoder installed for (u'json',) from kombu

Tags: django, celery, kombu

I think I am missing a step somewhere but I've been looking around and cant find it. When I run my celery task, I get thrown this error message `no encoder installed for (u'json',)` when I call `get_task.delay(args)`. Am i suppose to have my own custom serialization?

settings.py

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json', 
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

I also tried `get_task.apply_async((args), serializer='json')`. This seems to hang. Nothing is running. I checked my `workers`, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a stray comma at the end of `CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER`. Remove it.